# Как изменить цвет рамки окна в wxPython?

Tags: python, python-3.x, окно, wxpython

Как можно изменить цвет рамки окна приложения `wxPython`?

Например, сделать прозрачным, синим или черным. Я говорю про рамку, в которой находится название окна и кнопки "закрыть" или "свернуть приложение".

Хотелось бы узнать, как это можно сделать с использование `wxPython`?

Answer (score 0):

Это невозможно, так как внешний вид рамки определяется операционной системой.

Вы можете создать собственную рамку (см. [пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51000320/wxpython-change-the-headers-color)).